# Errors in variable, statistics/econometrics, measurement error

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, statistics, instrumental-variable

I didn't understand the deduction involving Plim. Why do the Plim of the terms on the left translate as variance in the first two cases?
[here is the continuation of the print. were i have the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDMEi.png)
[image: here is the continuation of the print. were i have the question]

Comment: It's a good question because, unless the mean of $X$, namely E($X$), is zero, I don't see how they can use what they've used as an estimate of the variance = Var($X$) = E($X^2$) - E($X)^2$. Clearly, the sum of the squares divided by $n$ would be a consistent of the variance if E($X$) was equal to zero but I don't think it says that anywhere in the statement ? Could I have missed that ?

Comment: my point is that I think the left hand side of the first expression should be: plim $\left(\sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{n} \right)$ -  plim $\left(\frac{\sum x_{i}}{n} \right)^2$ but I'm not clear why the second term is not there ? I'm either confused or it's a typo.